# Use PHP or Javascript to get all Cookie/Session key and values from visitor's browser

Tags: php, javascript, curl

Is there a way to get all Cookie/Session Keys and Values from user browsers that are not related to the current site they are visiting but retrieved based on their history of cookies stored and current session from other sites?

Comment: Such as his bank account info and his web mail "Remember me" code?

Comment: Why?  What are you trying to do that you need to do this for?  Perhaps there is something else that may work, but unless you detail your problem, all that we can say is no...

Comment: I need to retrieve information and track cookie details for kids visiting sites that they shouldn't be visiting through a secure members only web portal upon request of parents. This is to be done by setting a specific page as default page when opening a browser for the first time via javascript. Primarily to find web browsing behaviour of kids and this is to be done without any installation of a software which is why I need this web based

Comment: Additionally the page is opened to specific ip addresses that are authorized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that this is not possible from server driven code (meaning JS that's loaded from a server).

And it should not be possible either.  That ability (even if authorized) could be used for very nefarious purposes.  The potential security holes are huge.  I understand that you say that it's an authorized tool by the user.  But think of the social engineering aspects.  I could make a seemingly benign or useful tool to the user, but in the background collect all sorts of important and dangerous information to sell or use for worse tasks.

Now, with that said, it *may* be possible to write an extension for the browser for this task.  But that violates the "install nothing" comment that you made.  Short of that, it's not possible and it should not be possible.

One other possibility would be to not use cookies at all for this task.  If you're goal is to track what kids are using on the browser, why not just use a proxy?  Set up a proxy that tracks and filters everything on a computer.  Then either block unwanted sites, or simply log their usage for later review.  Sure, a smart user could change their proxy settings, but that's a limitation for any solution (especially one reliant upon cookies, they could just clear all cookies before closing the browser, or configure the browser to do so for them).

So, in short, I'd suggest finding another solution to your problem.  The one which you seek won't work and would be very dangerous even if it did...

Comment: Good idea. How would you set up Proxy server in a browser to accomplish this?

Comment: @Jae: I would suggest doing some research and if you still need help posting a new question as that's a bigger question and outside of the scope of this one...

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't get cookies from other sites. Cookies have a [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path) and cookies won't be delivered to requesters outside that scope.

If you could do such a thing then the browser would have a **major** security problem.